# Possible to remove/deactivate variables from an executed line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Is it possible to remove/deactivate variables from a line of code once it has been executed? If not, what are my other options? I wrote a code here to demonstrate what I mean:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
ent_var1 = StringVar()
ent_var2 = StringVar()
ent_var3 = StringVar()
cbtn_var1 = BooleanVar()
cbtn_var2 = BooleanVar()
cbtn_var3 = BooleanVar()

ent1 = Entry(textvariable=ent_var1).pack()
ent2 = Entry(textvariable=ent_var2).pack()
ent3 = Entry(textvariable=ent_var3).pack()
cbtn1 = Checkbutton(text=1, variable=cbtn_var1).pack(side = LEFT)
cbtn2 = Checkbutton(text=2, variable=cbtn_var2).pack(side = LEFT)
cbtn3 = Checkbutton(text=3, variable=cbtn_var3).pack(side = LEFT)

# prints what was written in entires
def set_variables():
    lbl1 = ent_var1.get()
    lbl2 = ent_var2.get()
    lbl3 = ent_var3.get()
    print lbl1, lbl2, lbl3
    return

# calls set_variables
btn1 = Button(root, text="Done!", command=set_variables).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When you fill the entries and press "Done!", what was written is printed. But how do I make it so that when I press the checkboxes, the entry linked to it will not be printed the next the I press "Done!"? The checkbox with the text "1" should be linked with the first entry, and so on.

I came up with this:

```
def should_print():
    global lbl_print
    if cbtn1:
        lbl_print += lbl1
    if cbtn2:
        lbl_print += lbl2
    if cbtn3:
        lbl_print += lbl3
```

But it would only print the values of my variables at that very moment, not the variables themselves (meaning I'd have to run this code every time a variable changes).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very hard to understand. I *think* what you want is for `set_variables` to only print the variables associated with a checked checkbox. If so, does the following do what you want?

```
def set_variables():
    to_print = []
    if cbtn_var1.get():
        to_print.append(ent_var1.get())
    if cbtn_var2.get():
        to_print.append(ent_var2.get())
    if cbtn_var3.get():
        to_print.append(ent_var3.get())
    print " ".join(to_print)
    return
```

There are other ways to accomplish the same thing, but I'm guessing your main goal is to decide what to print based on which checkbuttons are checked. This does that, albeit in a rather ham-fisted manner.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply check in your `set_variables` function if each button is pressed? For example:

```
def set_variables():
    if not cbtn_var1.get():
        print ent_var1.get(),
    if not cbtn_var2.get():
        print ent_var2.get(),
    if not cbtn_var3.get():
        print ent_var3.get(),
    print
```

The commas at the end of each `print` statement will cause it to not print a newline, which is taken care of by the `print` at the end. Also, this will make so that if the box *is* checked, the value they entered *won't* print. If you want it to print only if the box is checked, then remove the `not`s.

If you refactor your code a little bit, you can do the same thing with one line. First, add this line:

```
cbtn_var1 = BooleanVar()
cbtn_var2 = BooleanVar()
cbtn_var3 = BooleanVar()
buttonsAndValues = [(cbtn_var1,ent_var1), (cbtn_var2,ent_var2), (cbtn_var3,ent_var3)]
```

With the variables in a list, you can use a list comprehension in some Python magic:

```
def set_variables():
    print ' '.join(value.get() for checked, value in buttonsAndValues if checked.get())
```

If you haven't seen list comprehensions before, I'd suggest you read up about them - they can be very handy.

Comment: In Python3, if anyone else is wondering, you can do `print(ent_var3.get(),end='')` since you can't follow it with a comma as the answerer did here :)

Comment: Thank you so much, Rob! I'll definitely check it out :)